# OpenLayers 2 Marker disappears when switching between functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I'm working on an app which is handed down to me. 
(Because I do not have the time to rewrite this in OpenLayers 3, I'm struggling to get it to work in OpenLayers 2)

The previous programer created his own line measuring functionality, based on mouse events (down/move/up) I had to add freehand drawing amongst others. The initial use of the measurement tool works. If I switch to another drawingfeature, and switch back to the measuring tool, I loose the marker (a visor image).

A few oddities:
After selecting the measurement icon, I get a default pointer, if I click somewhere on the page, the marker reappears.

1. If I click and drag I get the marker only at the beginning of the
   line
2. If I click and release and click, drag, release, the line has
       the markers at both ends

The inherrited code:

**Functions:**

```
    function mouse_touch_down(event) {
    if ( pin_placement_enabled || distance_measurement_enabled ) {

          if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

        position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy);

        var rdx = longitude2rdx( position.lon );
        var rdy = lattitude2rdy( position.lat );

        if (pin_placement_enabled) {
            return place_pin(position, rdx, rdy);
        }
        else if (distance_measurement_enabled) {
            return place_distance_marker_1(position, rdx, rdy);
        }
        else {
            sketch_pen_down = 0;
        }
    }
}

function mouse_touch_move(event) {
    if (distance_measurement_enabled) {
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        else event.returnValue = false;

        move_distance_marker_2(event);

    } else if (sketch_pen_down)
        sketch_add_point(event.xy);

}

function mouse_touch_up(event) {
    if (sketch_pen_down) {
        sketch_pen_down = 0;
        sketch_add_label(event);
    }
    if (distance_measurement_enabled) {
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    if ( distance_line != 0 ) {
        if ( ! lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id] ) {
           lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id] = {};
        }
    /**
     * @todo: save distance line and markers data
     */
        lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id].layertype = 'marker';
        lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id].mrkr1 = distance_marker_1;
        lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id].mrkr2 = distance_marker_2;
    }

    distance_markers.push(distance_marker_1);
    distance_markers.push(distance_marker_2);
    distance_marker_1 = 0;
    distance_marker_2 = 0;
    distance_line = 0;
    distance_label = 0;
    }

}

/**
 * sketch function => freehand/lineControl
 */
function toggle_freeline() {
    freeline_enabled = !freeline_enabled;
    document.getElementById("sketchicon").style.border = (freeline_enabled ? "3px solid red" : "3px solid white");
    if (freeline_enabled) {
        activate_pan_and_zoom(0);
        if ( ! vector_layer_id ) {
            create_vector_layer();
        }
        freelineControl.activate();
    }
    else {
        activate_pan_and_zoom(1);
        freelineControl.deactivate();
    }
}

function place_distance_marker_1(position, rdx, rdy) {
     distance_marker_1_position = position;
     var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,21);
     var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-10, -10);
     var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("img/marker-userclick-21x21.png", size, offset);

     distance_marker_1 = new OpenLayers.Marker(distance_marker_1_position, icon);
     marker_layer.addMarker(distance_marker_1);

     distance_marker_1_rdx = rdx;
     distance_marker_1_rdy = rdy;
}

function move_distance_marker_2(event) {
     position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy);
     var rdx = <?=(($klic_rd_ll_x + $klic_rd_ur_x) / 2);?> + ((<?=(($klic_rd_ur_x - $klic_rd_ll_x) / 2);?> * position.lon * <?=$square_size;?>) / <?=$klic_px_width;?>);
     var rdy = <?=(($klic_rd_ll_y + $klic_rd_ur_y) / 2);?> + ((<?=(($klic_rd_ur_y - $klic_rd_ll_y) / 2);?> * position.lat * <?=$square_size;?>) / <?=$klic_px_height;?>);

     distance_marker_2_position = position;
     var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,21);
     var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-10, -10);
     var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("img/marker-userclick-21x21.png", size, offset);

     if (distance_marker_2) {
          distance_marker_2.moveTo(map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(event.xy));

     } else {
          distance_marker_2 = new OpenLayers.Marker(distance_marker_2_position, icon);
          marker_layer.addMarker(distance_marker_2);
     }

     distance_marker_2_rdx = rdx;
     distance_marker_2_rdy = rdy;

     if (distance_marker_1) {
          var distance = Math.sqrt(((distance_marker_2_rdx - distance_marker_1_rdx) * (distance_marker_2_rdx - distance_marker_1_rdx)) + ((distance_marker_2_rdy - distance_marker_1_rdy) * (distance_marker_2_rdy - distance_marker_1_rdy)));
          if (distance >= 100)
                distance = Math.round(distance) + "m";
          else {
                distance = (Math.round(distance * 10) + "m");
                distance = distance.slice(0, -2) + "," + distance.slice(-2);
          }

        if ( ! vector_layer_id ) {
            create_vector_layer();
        }

        if (distance_line) {
            vector_layer.removeFeatures([distance_line, distance_label]);
            delete lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id];
        }

        distance_line = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(distance_marker_1_position.lon, distance_marker_1_position.lat), new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(distance_marker_2_position.lon, distance_marker_2_position.lat)]));
        distance_line.style = { "strokeColor": "#008030", "strokeWidth": 3 };

        distance_label = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point((distance_marker_1_position.lon + distance_marker_2_position.lon) / 2, (distance_marker_1_position.lat + distance_marker_2_position.lat) / 2));
        distance_label.style = { "strokeColor": "#000000", "strokeWidth": 1, "fontColor": "#000000", "labelOutlineColor": "#ffffff", "labelOutlineWidth": 4, "label": distance, "labelAlign": "cm" };

        vector_layer.addFeatures([distance_line, distance_label]);
        if (distance_line) {
            lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id] = {};
            lbl2drawfeature[distance_line.geometry.id].lbl = distance_label.id
        }
    }
}


function add_label(xy, refid) {
    var textpoint = Math.round( xy.length /2 ) -1;
    var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(xy[textpoint].x, xy[textpoint].y);
    var label_text = prompt('Tekst voor op de kaart', '');

    if (label_text) {
        lbl = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(position.lon, position.lat));
        lbl.style = { "strokeColor": "#000000", "strokeWidth": 1, "fontColor": "#000000", "labelOutlineColor": "#ffffff", "labelOutlineWidth": 4, "label": label_text, "labelAlign": "cm" };

        vector_layer.addFeatures(lbl);
        lbl2drawfeature[refid].lbl = lbl.id;
        return label_text;
    }

    n_sketch_shapes++;
    return '';
}

function toggle_distance() {
    distance_measurement_enabled = !distance_measurement_enabled;
    if ( pin_placement_enabled  ) {
        toggle_pin_placement();
    }
    if (!distance_measurement_enabled ) {
        vector_layer.removeAllFeatures();
        remove_distance_markers();
    }
    document.getElementById("sketchicon").style.border = (distance_measurement_enabled ? "3px solid red" : "3px solid white");

    if (distance_measurement_enabled) {
        activate_pan_and_zoom(0);
        if ( ! vector_layer_id ) {
            create_vector_layer();
        }
        create_marker_layer();

     }
     else {
          if (distance_marker_2 && (!distance_marker_1)) marker_layer.removeMarker(distance_marker_2);
          if (!pin_placement_enabled) activate_pan_and_zoom(1);
     }
}

function toggle_drawing_item(item) {
    for( var i = 0; i <= drawtype.length; i++ ) {
        switch( drawtype[i]) {
            case 'pin_placement':
                if( pin_placement_enabled || item == 'pin_placement' ) {
                    toggle_pin_placement();
                }
                break;
            case 'distance_measurement':
                if( distance_measurement_enabled || item == 'distance_measurement' ) {
                    toggle_distance_measurement();
                }
                break;
            case 'polyline':
                if( polyline_enabled || item == 'polyline' ) {
                    toggle_polyline();
                }
                break;
            case 'polygon':
                if( polygon_enabled || item == 'polygon' ) {
                    toggle_polygon();
                }
                break;
            case 'pointer':
                if( pointer_enabled || item == 'pointer' ) {
                    toggle_pointer();
                }
                break;
            case 'freeline':
                if( freeline_enabled || item == 'freeline' ) {
                    toggle_freeline();
                }
                break;
            case 'eraser':
                if( eraser_enabled || item == 'eraser' ) {
                    toggle_eraser();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Layers and Features:**

```
    var sketchSymbolizers = {
    "Point": {
        pointRadius: 10,
        externalGraphic: "/img/marker-userclick-21x21.png",
        fillColor: "white",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: "#333333"
    },
    "Line": {
        strokeWidth: 3,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: "#666666",
    },
    "Polygon": {
        strokeWidth: 2,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: "#666666",
        fillColor: "white",
        fillOpacity: 0.3
    }
};

var style = new OpenLayers.Style();
style.addRules([
    new OpenLayers.Rule({symbolizer: sketchSymbolizers})
]);
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({"default": style});


var vector_layer            = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    'Vector'
    , {styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ strokeColor: '#ff4000', strokeWidth: sketch_line_width, fillOpacity: 0.2, fillColor: '#ff4000'  })}
    );

var freelineControl         = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature ( vector_layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, { handlerOptions: { freehand: true } });
freelineControl.events.register( 'featureadded', freelineControl, function (e) {
                                            ++freelineCtrlId;
                                            freelineControl.typeid = 'freeline_' + freelineCtrlId;
                                            console.log(e.feature.geometry.components);
                                            lbl2drawfeature[e.feature.geometry.id] = {};
                                            var lbl_location = Math.round( e.feature.geometry.components.length / 2 );
                                            lableText = add_label( e.feature.geometry.components, e.feature.geometry.id );
                                            lbl2drawfeature[e.feature.geometry.id].layertype = 'vector';
                                            for( var i =0; i < e.feature.geometry.components.length; ++i ) {
                                                console.log(e.feature.geometry.components[i]);
                                            }
//                                          console.log(e.feature.geometry.bounds);
//                                          console.log(e.feature.geometry.componentTypes);
                                        });
var navigationControl       = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation();
var keyboardDefaultsControl = new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults;
var attributionControl      = new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution;

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "maplayer",
    projection: "EPSG:900913",
    layers: ol_layers,
    center: [0, 0],
    maxExtent: [-1, -1, 1, 1],
    zoom: currentzoom,
    controls: [ navigationControl, keyboardDefaultsControl, attributionControl, lineControl, polygonControl, selectControl, eraserControl, freelineControl ] // , measureControl ]
});

map.events.register("zoomend", null, highlight_zoom_button);
map.events.register("mousedown", map, mouse_touch_down);
map.events.register("mouseup", map, mouse_touch_up);
map.events.register("mousemove", map, mouse_touch_move);
map.events.register("touchstart", map, mouse_touch_down);
map.events.register("touchend", map, mouse_touch_up);
map.events.register("touchmove", map, mouse_touch_move);
```

**jQuery to switch feature:**

```
    var measure_src  = 'img/icon-mark-userclick-60x60.png';
var drawing_src  = 'img/icon-sketch-64x64.png';
var polyline_src = 'img/polyline_60x60.png';
var polygon_src  = 'img/polygon_60x60.png';
var eraser_src   = 'img/eraser_60x60.png';
var pointer_src  = 'img/pointer_60x60.png';
var freeline_src = 'img/freehand_60x60.png';
var measure_src  = 'img/icon-mark-userclick-60x60.png';

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.draw').on( 'click', function(e) {
        map.raiseLayer(map.getLayersByName('Vector')[0], map.layers.length);
        switch( $(this).attr('id') ) {
            case 'freelineicon':
                $( '#drawbar' ).toggle();
                $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src', freeline_src );
                $( '#sketch' ).css('border-style','3px solid red');
                toggle_drawing_item('freeline');
                activeDrawControl = 'freeline';
                break;
            case 'measureicon':
                $( '#drawbar' ).toggle();
                $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src', measure_src );
                $( '#sketch' ).css('border-style','3px solid red');
                toggle_drawing_item('distance_measurement');
                activeDrawControl = 'measure';
                break;
            case 'polylineicon':
                $( '#drawbar' ).toggle();
                $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src', polyline_src );
                $( '#sketch' ).css('border-style','3px solid red');
                toggle_drawing_item('polyline');
                activeDrawControl = 'polyline';
                break;
            case 'polygonicon':
                $( '#drawbar' ).toggle();
                $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src', polygon_src );
                $( '#sketch' ).css('border-style','3px solid red');
                toggle_drawing_item('polygon');
                activeDrawControl = 'polygon';
                break;
            case 'erasericon':
                $( '#drawbar' ).toggle();
                $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src', eraser_src );
                $( '#sketch' ).css('border-style','3px solid red');
                toggle_drawing_item('eraser');
                activeDrawControl = 'eraser';
                break;
            case 'pointericon':
                $( '#drawbar' ).toggle();
                $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src', pointer_src );
                $( '#sketch' ).css('border-style','3px solid red');
                toggle_drawing_item('pointer');
                activeDrawControl = 'pointer';
                break;
            case 'sketchicon':
                activeDrawControl = 'none';
                if ( $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src' ) != drawing_src ) {
                    $( '#sketch' ).attr( 'src', drawing_src );
                    $( '#sketch' ).css('border-style','none');
                }
                else {
                    $( '#drawbar' ).toggle();
                }
                toggle_drawing_item('sketching');
                map.raiseLayer(map.getLayersByName('Boxes')[0], map.layers.length);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

How can I avoid the marker from not being instantiated at the next measurement, when switching between a drawingcontrol and the mouse event directed measurement

Your input/comments will be much appreciated